# How do I use !! in a function

Tags: haskell

When I look at getting the nth element in haskell all I see is people referring to !! notation

How do I use it in a function, so far I have tried

```
module Main where
main :: IO ()
main =  do   
        let line = [4.9.45.3]   
        print $ listofints line 


listofints :: Int -> [Int]
listofints = \xs !! 2
```

I never seem to get the idea of **how to use hoogle** and also **how to pass a list from main to a** function

Any help will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to use Hoogle:**

You can see from Hoogle that the type of `!!` is

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

`!!` takes a list of `a`s and an `Int` as the index. Since there are parentheses around the function name, this means that `!!` is an *infix* operator, so we write that as

```
xs !! 3
```

Note that it can be treated as a prefix operator if we wrap it in parens:

```
(!!) xs 3
```

**How to pass a list from `main`:**

`listofints` doesn't *take* a list, it *returns* a list. So first, you need to fix the signature of `listofints`:

```
listofints :: [Int] -> Int
listofints xs = xs !! 2
```

or

```
listofints = \xs -> xs !! 2
```

or, in point-free style:

```
listofints = (flip (!!) 2)
```

Comment: This is what I get when i change listofints function : Couldn't match type `Int' with `Int -> Int'
    Expected type: [Int -> Int]
      Actual type: [Int]

Comment: I fixed my example, but you really need to read a Haskell tutorial. My function had the signature `[Int]->Int->Int`, which meant that it took a list and an `Int` and returned a `Int`. Now the signature is `[Int]->Int` which means it does not take an index argument.

Comment: yay I was able to figure it out with your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not with the `!!` operator; it's with defining a function, declaring its type, and also apparently with writing a list.

Here's how you use the `!!` operator:

```
items = [1,2,3,4]
secondItem = items !! 2
-- secondItem will be the number 3
```

I'll leave the rest of getting the program correct up to you.